# Running a Windows service at two specific times during the day

Tags: c#, windows, events, service, time

I have a simple Windows service in C# that copies over a database of pictures into a directory. I need it to do this twice a day: once at 6:00 am and again at 6:00 pm.

What kind of code can I implement to have it check the time of day and if it is 6:00 am or pm then run a few methods of code?

Comment: Just use Windows task scheduler. Don't bother making it a windows service.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @John Saunders: You forgot to take out the extra 'n' ;)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: I didn't forget - I didn't _see_ it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend separating scheduling logic from business logic.

Use something like [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) to address your scheduling needs. It uses cron style scheduling syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Task scheduler should be more than enough to run your app at the time you want the job done. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx